# "such that" or "so that"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

I saw the following definition, but I don't know why "such that" is used instead of "so that":

> To manipulate two or more people **such that** they dispute or conflict with one another in a way that is to one's benefit or advantage.

Answer (score 0):

> To manipulate two or more people **such that** they dispute or conflict with one another in a way that is to one's benefit or advantage.

emphasizes the quality, manner or the way of "To manipulate two or more people" (similar to "to the extent that").

> To manipulate two or more people **so that** they dispute or conflict with one another in a way that is to one's benefit or advantage.

emphasizes the purpose or consequences of "To manipulate two or more people" (similar to "in order that").

Comment: Could you analyze the syntax of "such that" in relation to the rest of the sentence?

Comment: It is a conjunction introducing a subordinate clause where the manner of the main clause is presented by the subordinate clause.

Comment: Do you mean the clause headed by "such that" modifies the main clause?

Comment: One characteristic of an adverbial subordinate clause is its permutability. For example, a because-clause could move to sentence-initial position. But that's not the case of the "such that" clause.

Comment: Yes the clause following "such that", like "they dispute or conflict with one another..."  present the quality of the main clause "manipulate two or more people". However, note that your example is a definition (phrase) not a complete sentence. It does not have main clause.

Comment: Suppose we turn the definition into a sentence this way: John manipulated the three girls such that they disputed with one another in a way that was to his benefit or advantage."

Comment: If the "such that" clause is an adverbial subordinate clause, why can't it be fronted?

Comment: _So_ is an adverb. _Such_ is an adjective. _So that_ introduces an adverbial clause. _Such that_ introduces an adjective clause.

Comment: You mean the "such that" clause is an adjectival clause?

Comment: How could an adjectival clause modify a preceding main clause? Any examples?

Comment: Yes.  _Such that_ introduces an adjective clause.

Comment: https://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-so-that-and-vs-such-that/

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16883/difference-between-so-that-and-such-that